# Calling jquery function of child page displayed in iframe from parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I've got a page where clicking a div calls a function:

```
$("#fontOpenSans").on("click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $("#dlVersion *").css("font-family", $(this).css("font-family"));
    localStorage.font_family = $(this).css("font-family");
});
```

I am showing this page in iframe now i want to call same function from out side of this page (From the page in which iframe is placed).

If I declare it like this:

```
function callfontOpenSans() {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $("#dlVersion *").css("font-family", $(this).css("font-family"));
    localStorage.font_family = $(this).css("font-family");
}
```

Then I can call it like this:

```
$('#iframeID').contentWindow.callfontOpenSans();
```

How would I call a function written in the first way from outside the page (i.e. the parent page)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello friends i got answer for my question

```
$('#iframeId').contents().find('#fontOpenSans').click();
```

> solved my problem 
>   thanks
>
> will work when both pages are on same domain

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$('#iframeID')[0].contentWindow["callfontOpenSans"]();
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi Kundan thanks for u r reply. i know this way i can call the function but you are calling function which has a name i want to call function declare in first way